# Bolt custom routing and extensions

Tags: routes, bolt-cms

On my bolt instance, I've overriden entries' routing to remove content-type from uri, ie:

```
http://example.com/my-first-entry
http://example.com/another-entry
```

I've also installed the sitemap extension, but as it defines routing like:

```
http://example.com/sitemap
http://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

I can't access my sitemap as my entries routing is the first one matched.

I tried to redefine a routing for sitemap *before* entries but the extension can't be called statically. I also tried to define a exclusion requirement in entries route but it doesn't work either.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `app/config/routing.yml` you can create a specific route for the sitemap itself:

```
# Sitemap
sitemap:
  path:               /sitemap.xml
  defaults:           { _controller: 'Bolt\Extension\Bolt\Sitemap\Extension::sitemap' }
```

Comment: I tried but the extension doesn't offer any controller (bolt/sitemap extension)

Comment: We have added functionality to the upcoming Bolt 2.1 that will allow the above to work properly for your use-case.